# jquery for loop instead of underscore.js _.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

ok, well i am not good with looping so here it goes..

i want to for loop this _.each

```
 _.each(data, function (item) {
                            newData.push({
                                id: item.FormID,  //id part present in data
                                text: item.FormName  //string to be displayed
                            });
                        });
```

_.each is a function of underscore.js library.

i don't want to use the library, just the plain jquery or javascript.

i tried like this.. i know its wrong. but have tried and failed.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < data; i++ ) {
    newData.push({
        id: item.FormID,  //id part present in data
        text: item.FormName  //string to be displayed
    });

}
```

Comment: Replace `item.FormID` with `data[i].FormID`. Same for `FormName`, or create a variable called `item` and assign it with `data[i]` before the push call in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like this:

```
$.each(data, function (index,value) {
                        newData.push({
                            id: value.FormID,  //id part present in data
                            text: value.FormName  //string to be displayed
                        });
                    });
```

you can also use for loop like this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
    newData.push({
       id: data[i].FormID,  //id part present in data
       text: data[i].FormName  //string to be displayed
     });

}
```

Comment: Thankyou. both of your codes are working, i tried both..
But which one should i go for.
I mean should i go for jquery or simple javascript??

Comment: $.each needs to include jquery library in your HTML, and if you don't want to include jquery library then go with simple javascript for loop for(var i=0;i<...

Answer (score 2):

It is same in jQuery,

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
    newData.push({
        id: item.FormID, //id part present in data
        text: item.FormName //string to be displayed
    });
});
```

Comment: In jQuery, item is the second argument

Answer (score 1):

```
i < data
```

Should be

```
i < data.length
```

Assuming data is an array

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript arrays have [`forEach` methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) of their own:

```
data.forEach(function(item) {
    newData.push({ id: item.FormId, text: item.FormName });
});
```

Or, since you seem to be transforming the `data` array into another array, you could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var newData = data.map(function(item) {
    return {
        id: item.FormId,
        text: item.FormName
    };
});
```

If `newData` already has things in it, then you could use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to append the results from `map`:

```
var newData = [ ... ];
newData = newData.concat(data.map(function(item) {
    return {
        id: item.FormId,
        text: item.FormName
    };
}));
```

You could even use [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
newData.push.apply(newData, data.map(function(item) { ... }));
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not what I call *plain*, it's already a library by itself, and it's a library in which the arguments of the iterator for `each` are inverted, compared to the *plain javascript*.

Unless you care about IE8, I suggest you to use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which is available in *plain javascript*:

```
data.forEach(function (item) {
    newData.push({
        id: item.FormID,  //id part present in data
        text: item.FormName  //string to be displayed
    });
});
```

(And if you care about IE8, you can use the [polyfill from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill))